# Executing .bat file from powershell button click event

Tags: batch-file

I was working with some powershell button that calls a .bat file.  I have looked around but it only appears to work the other way around.  I'm trying to figure out the syntax to call a .bat file from powershell button.   This seems to work from command line, but I'm having issues with using it within my button.  Any sugestions?

```
$StartButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StartButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 450)
$StartButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,43)
$StartButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", "10.5")
$StartButton.Text = "Start Tuner"
$StartButton.Add_Click(invoke-command{C:\temp\Map.bat})
$tunerForm.Controls.Add($StartButton)
```

Thanks anything is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Start-Process and -wait

```
Start-Process myBatch.bat -wait
```

That way, your script does not do anything else while that script runs / completes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys..   I found the answer..  Invoke-Expression "cmd /c c:\path\to\batch\file.bat"

Sorry...